# how to Get the list of sites (domains) from MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

so I am new in StackOverflow :), I have a problem to answer a question in php5,

**This is the question :** 
Create a PHP 5.4 script to check availability of many Sites (via Echo Protocol):
    * Get the list of sites (domains) from MySQL database.
so I write this script and I want if it's the good answer :

```
    <?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are depricated

Comment: Use mysqli instead of mysql_

Comment: The script you have is only printing the list of tables in the database. I assume that one of these tables holds the list of sites that you're supposed to check. Do you know the name of the table?

Comment: @Philippe Signoret : yes that what I am trying to get the list of site, have you any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: Code reviews are on topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$con = mysqli_connect(‘hostname’, ‘username’, ‘password’, ‘database’);
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select column_name from table_name");
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $data['column_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will tell you the databases that have rights to be connected to

```
mysql_connect('localhost') or die ("Connect error");

$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Why not PDO? As @Robin Webdev says, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a database before you use mysql_query.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
//Write code to Check the connection
mysql_select_db('database_name', $connection);
//Write code to query
```

But as Robin mentioned in the comment, mysql* apis are deprecated. Use Mysqli or Pdo_Mysql. details here: https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

Comment: Please use Mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: Yes Kees Sonnema.. I agree. But in the answer I pointed out what was missing in the question.